# Слово-привид "доєднати"/"доєднувати". Чи існує? Чи питоме?

Tags: етимологія, дієслова, існування-слова

Тільки для неозначеної форми дієслова `доєднати` [ґуґл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1l4.1107.1107.0.1342.1.1.0.0.0.0.110.110.0j1.1.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.109.8ZlXAKW6FhY) видає 2540 результатів.

[Доєднав](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...162859.162859.0.163067.1.1.0.0.0.0.99.99.1.1.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.wIuraM65uCU): 265 результатів.

[Доєднала](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...90241.90703.0.91148.2.2.0.0.0.0.148.239.1j1.2.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.U9g8g76-eVw): 47 результатів.

[Доєднали](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...93439.94897.0.95257.3.3.0.0.0.0.103.275.2j1.3.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.MOqxh_YgivY): 1800 результатів.

Для неозначеної форми дієслова `доєднувати` [ґуґл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1l2j0i13i30k1l2.44230.45109.0.45681.5.5.0.0.0.0.117.470.3j2.5.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.218.krHf7a6-EGc) видає 157 результатів.

На [державному сайті](http://decentralization.gov.ua/discussion/item/id/1616) знаходжу таке:

`Яким чином доєднати до вже створеної ОТГ інші сільські ради і чим керуватися?`

АЄОА! СУМ такого слова не знає. Словники України Онлайн такого слова не знають. Корпус української мови такого слова не знає.

Звідки воно взялося?

Comment: Власна версія: гібрид від *приєднувати(ся)* і *долучати(ся)*.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko як на мене - прекрасне слово виходить.

Comment: З погляду [морфеміки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Українська_морфеміка) — проблем немає: _придати_ — _додати_. Приростки _при_ й _до_ мають схожі ролі: _доїхати_ — _приїхати_, _принести_ — _донести_. Ось думка: у мові є комбінація _оє_ — дв**оє**, а як питомість звучання щодо _доє_? Ось окрім _приєднати_ є ще _приємність_. Якщо переглянути, з иншими йотованими дієсловами, проблем наче немає — _доїхати_, але _при_ варіятивніший. Раптове питання [фонетики](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Українська_фонетика). Щодо лоґістики питань немає: приєднати до вже щось єднального.

Comment: @Follower витратите трохи часу на повноцінну відповідь, коли буде?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Морфеміка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Дієслова *єднати* чи *єднувати* зі схожими по суті приростками **до-** та **при-**.

Приростки **до-**, **при-** значаться початку або кінця дії:  ***за**працювати, **до**нести, **при**нести*. Не плутати зі суцільної доконаності, для цього є **з-**, **по-**, **про-**, **на-**.

Також **до-** — напряму дії: ***до**їхати*.

*Єднання* має початок, кінець і напрямок.

Найлоґічніше використовувати *доєднати* як напрямокове дієслово зі сполучником *до*:

— Вживано в прикладі запитання і в [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8).
— [Корпус лейпцизького університету](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014) (тільки *доєднати*): *до (49)*.

Дієслово *єднати* та приросток *до* поокремо є очевидно питомими.

---

Аби внести свою ясність, **різниця між словами**:
— *доєднати* — важливий напрям; увага на дієслові можлива, але вторинна;
— *приєднати* — увага на дієслові: спосіб чи час; можливість результату.

Також слушна думка щодо:
— При єдності
— До єдності

Отже:
— *Доєднати до чого?* — як напрям;
— *Як доєднати до чого?* — відшук напряму;
— *Як приєднати?* — як спосіб (час, варіянт дії);
— *Приєднати до чого?* — вельми обширне: як результат, спосіб чи важливість. Влучніше з иншими часами чи з контекстом.

*Своє.* Не бажано зловживати цим дієсловом:
— Якщо до клубу — (напр.) *вступити*, а не *приєднати**ся***;
— Влучний синонім: *долучати*.

Comment: от мені воно так і звучить: доєдную щось до чогось, а потім воно може бути вже й приєднане (коли я вже доєднав) до цього чогось. Одному мені так? Тобто, я доєдную ДО якоїсь єдності, а потім цей об’єкт знаходиться ПРИ цій єдності.

Comment: Мені до вподоби така думка, має право на існування.